# c# копировать таблица из mysql в sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

`INSERT INTO sqlite_connection.table_name SELECT * FROM mysql_connection.table_name;`

Comment: нашел это https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/07/sqlite-how-to-copy-table-to-another-database.html. Но это только для sqlite connection

Comment: Мне надо две сторон соединение mysql connection и sqlite connection

Comment: Я попробовал так while(reader.read())

Comment: while(reader.read()){insert into...}

Comment: Но это с большой данный занимает очень долго...